# How to format the display of JSON data in a tkinter.Text widget?

Tags: python, json, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-text

I have created a Python GUI that allows the user to create and save text files (technically a journal). Within the workspace (VS Code), I have created a JSON file of simple key/value pairs (technically a dictionary);  `"word": "definition"`.

I want the user to be able to click a button that opens a window with a tk.Text widget which contains the JSON data in a clear, readable, and alphabetical list form, but the data prints out as a multiline string separated by single quotes without any spaces or newlines inside the Text widget.

My desired outcome is a "read-only" list of key/value pairs, one per line, without all of the JSON syntax (double quotes, commas, and curly brackets).
I cannot find any solution to achieve this specific preference, and I'm still learning the capabilities of JSON data within a Python program. If there is a more suitable or configurable method, I am open to suggestions, but I hope there is a simple configuration to the Python syntax that dictates how the data prints in the Text widget.

Thank you for any insights given. I do not think the code would be relevant to address this but if needed, I can add it.

Comment: You can display multiple lines of text in a [`tkinter.Listbox`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190525055058id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html). So, to do what you want, you would would need to extract all the word & definition (key/value) pairs from the dictionary, each formatted as a single string, append it to a list. When done, the list can be sorted and its contents transferred to a `Listbox` as separate lines.

Comment: There is no pre-built solution. You just need to iterate over the data and insert it in the widget in whatever form you desire.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I am going to try to get the correct layout with the JSON module first, because I have it all set up, but if it isn't correct, I will move on to this method and update this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make use of the builtin `json` module, and use the `dump` method of a loaded json file, or `dumps` with a string like in this example:

```
import json
print(json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

resulting in

```
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

So instead of printing it directly, you can pass it through `json.dumps` and then add the result to your text widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

app = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(app)

text.pack()

json_val = json.loads('{"a": 5, "b": 7}')

for k in json_val:
    text.insert(tk.END, '{} = {}\n'.format(k,json_val[k]))
text.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
app.mainloop()
```

The above code produces this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I figured there should be some way to do it with the JSON module. But how exactly would I 'add' the result to the Text widget? I've been working with Python for awhile, but fairly recently began researching JSON for data.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer

Comment: Alright, thanks. I see what you mean. I may have to do it that way. But is there a way to remove the special characters, other than the colon between the strings? For a user unfamiliar with coding wouldn't understand why that extra stuff is there.

Comment: I'm also using the JSON file to identify "key" matches in the User's saved text file to provide definitions, but that is for later. So, I want to avoid having to hard-code the "dictionary" into the Python file because it is very long and I want to use the JSON with other features.

Comment: I've updated again with some re-formatting. I'm assuming here that your JSON data is only one level deep, otherwise it will print out sub-values on a single line again. To make it work for any nesting youd need to walk the tree yourself and indent it etc.  I also added the `DISABLED` value to make it read only.

Comment: Perfect! I've previously tried the DISABLED configuration and I got a blank Text widget, but I may have had something off. Thank you, I have found no answers through Google, so I had to create an account here ha. I will be needing this resource more as I progress.